# How to use c++ class objects from .mm file in other file?

Tags: c++, iphone

I have made two files that are MathUtils.h

```
#include "iostream"
```

and MathUtils.cpp

```
#include "MathUtils.h"

using namespace std;

//Box class .....................
class Box
{
private:
    double length;   // Length of a box
    double breadth;  // Breadth of a box
    double height;   // Height of a box
public:
    void setParameters(int l,int b,int h);
    int volume();
    int area();
};

void Box::setParameters(int l, int b, int h)
{
    length=l;
    breadth=b;
    height=h;
}

int Box::volume()
{
    return length*breadth*height;
}

int Box::area()
{
    return (2*(length*breadth) + 2*(breadth*height) + 2*(height*length));
}


//sphere class................
class Sphere
{
private:
    double pi=3.14;
    double r;
public:
    void setParameters(int radius);
    int volume();
    int area();
};

void Sphere::setParameters(int radius)
{
    r=radius;
}

int Sphere::volume()
{
    return (4/3)*pi*r*r;
}

int Sphere::area()
{
    return 4*pi*r*r;
}
```

How can we use this file in my project could any one help me.I have never use c++ files in my project so I want to know how can we use Box and Sphere class object in other viewController file.
Thanks!.

Comment: Have you googled it ?

Comment: If you use XCode see http://www.brandonpate.org/?p=34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your classes in the .h file.

For your example, move:

```
class Box
{
private:
    double length;   // Length of a box
    double breadth;  // Breadth of a box
    double height;   // Height of a box
public:
    void setParameters(int l,int b,int h);
    int volume();
    int area();
};

class Sphere
{
private:
    double pi=3.14;
    double r;
public:
    void setParameters(int radius);
    int volume();
    int area();
};
```

to *mathutils.h* and add `#include "mathutils.h"` to your viewController file.  Your member functions for Box should still be in `mathutils.c`

A function in your view controller can then make use of it:

```
{
  Box b;
  b.setParameters(1,2,3);
  int v = b.volume();
  int a = b.area();
}
```

Comment: and how can we make object Box in view controller where I have imported it, and call methods

Comment: Just a point of class design, you may want to move some of the functionality of setParameters to a constructor for the classes.  E.g. The above example would become:
{
  Box b(1,2,3);
  int v = b.volume();
  int a = b.area();
}

Comment: NSLog won't work for C++ classes.  I'm sure someone has figured out a trick to do it, but just use cout <<, printf or use NSLog() to print the value of a member function:  { NSLog(@"%d",box.volume()); }

Comment: By now every thing was working fine as your answer satisfies the question requirement +1 for that. But suddenly one problem has occurred : iostream file not found.What it means